# Displaying image from numpy Array sent via sockets

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sockets, opencv

I'm trying to make an streaming app that takes screenshots of a specific window and sends it over to the server and then server displays the imgs.

Capturing is done via (**WORKS**)

```
frame = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=win32gui.GetWindowRect(window)))
```

Frame sending: (**WORKS**)

```
dp = pickle.dumps(frame)
to_send = bytes(f"{len(dp):<{HEADER}}", FORMAT) + bytes(FRAME_MSG, FORMAT) + dp
client.send(to_send)
```

Receiving: (**WORKS**)

```
def receive_msg(msg_len, conn, buffer):
    msg = bytearray()
    while(len(msg) < msg_len):
        msg += conn.recv(buffer)
        # msg.append(conn.recv(buffer))
    return msg
```

```
msg = receive_msg(msg_len, conn, 1024)
arr = pickle.loads(msg)
```

Display: (**DOESN'T WORK**)

```
cv2.imshow('window',cv2.cvtColor(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Options I tried for display:

```
-------
image = cv2.imdecode(arr, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow('URL2Image',image)
-------
cv2.imshow('window', arr)
-------
img = Image.fromarray(arr, "RGB")
img.show()
-------
```

Parts that I labeled as working I have tested via sending sample numpy array data.

---EDIT---

Turns out `cv2.imshow()` needs to have `cv2.waitKey()` invoked somewhere below to work properly.
Thanks to everyone that tried to help.

Comment: Please try and make a *"Minimum Complete Reproducible Example"* https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example At the moment there are too may things we cannot see that could be causing the problems. You should have all the `import` statements and the **actual**, **minimal**, **runnable** code. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What is your array shape?
Make sure you transform it not just into 1d array but into 2d or 3d array (depending if it is gray-scale or color).

You have to somehow specify the x and y (and possibly z) dimensions of the expected array - either in the message or hard-coded into the code on the receiving side.

Of course, sending those as parameters into the message is better but for debugging I suggest, start with hard coding the dimensions to transform it to the proper 2d/3d shape. If it works then that is the issue. Then figure out how to send it as a message along with the image itself.

Comment: Output of print(arr.shape) is: (628, 882, 3)
So shape is not an issue.
Also i'm not getting any errors from cv2.imshow function. Just window that pops is inresposine and has to be closed (data is flowing in the meantime).

Comment: If data is flowing in the meantime that means maybe show() is called on many many image instances and that may cause the hanging? Have you tried to save to image to file before calling show()? If the images save to file successfully and look OK, that is a hint to look in that direction. Maybe even put a wait statement for about 10 seconds at that point of the code.